# How do I make a stable sorting algorithm that uses an unstable algorithm as a subroutine

Tags: algorithms, sorting

The stable algorithm has to run in O(n) time and must call the following unstable algorithm at least once.

EDIT: Calling unstablesort() is free (costs 0 operations).

```
def unstablesort(l):
    return selectionsort(shuffled(l)) # shuffled(l) returns list l randomized
```

This is apparently an easy question but frankly I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please reproduce the problem statement as in your homework. An O(n) general sort is not possible.

Comment: Question 1: In which situation does it not matter that the unstable sort is unstable? Question 2: How can you create this situation?

Comment: @gnasher729 When there are no duplicates, I can create that by looping through the list and creating a set but then I don't see how to go about adding the duplicates back in and keeping it O(n). For example if all the items are equal

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Unstable sorting shuffles the data in an unrecoverable way (because identical keys are... identical), so you must somehow save the initial position information.

Comment: Make a list of key : index pairs? Or duplicate the whole list, sort one and compare the two somehow? I'm not seeing a way to make it work

Comment: @user19843013: you are close.

Comment: Which guess was close, the key index pairs or duplicating the whole list?

Comment: @user19843013: sorry, I am not going to ease your task.